# How to load own font from CSS file into JavaFX application (I'm using now JDK 8u45)

Tags: css, font-face, javafx-8

When I used JDK 8u11 I could see in application text in my own font. But when I upgraded my Java to JDK 8u45 I see that my font wasn't loaded. I can't see any warning in my console in Eclipse (I'm using Luna). I used this CSS, but now it is not working.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My-Font';
    src: url('../font/My-Font.otf');
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: There is no problem in the way you are loading the fonts. Are you adding the fonts to the controls?

Comment: I added style to buttons `.button .text {-fx-font-family: 'My-Font';}`
Everything was working before I upgraded Java.

Comment: This looks fine to me and it works on my machine with Java 1.8.0_45

Comment: I just committed a [repository](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/FontLoad), which loads font and displays it on Label and Button. You may try it.

Comment: @Lenka you can try to load font in code somewhere in the begining of your app before setting css. like this: `Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"), 20);` no need to use it, just load it once.

Comment: @varren thank you very much. Now it is working. :-)
@ItachiUchiha I used similar method: `scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/styles.css");` but I couldn't load font. I tried also your method but it wasn't working.

Comment: @Lenka That is strange. I works fine on my Mac 10.8.5 + Java 1.8.0_45. I even tried changing my directory and using `src: url('../fonts/GoodDog.otf');`, it just worked fine. Can you post details about your environment? It might be a bug.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Could you specify what details would you like to know? I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit OS, Service Pack 1), Java1.8.0_45, Eclipse Luna 4.4.1

Comment: @Lenka I tried it on Windows 8.1 + Java 1.8.0_45 and it runs just fine. Though, I do not have a Windows 7 machine to test on, I am of the view that it should work fine.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I tried it and it was not working. I solved this issue thanks to varren's answer.